# ¿Cómo puedo pasar el código script que está en el body de un archivo .blade de laravel a un archivo .js por separado?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Tengo un archivo **`app.blade.php`** de laravel donde escribí código javascript, precisamente una petición ajax que va dirigido al controlador en laravel, pero no sé como pasarlo a un archivo .js por separado ya que ocupo sintaxis blade en el script del archivo en la ruta para enviarlo al controlador de laravel y al redirigirlo a otra página **`app.blade.php`**, ¿Cómo puedo escribir esa sintaxis blade en un archivo javascript? ya que entiendo que en javascript no se puede escribir la sintaxis de blade.

**Código del script al final del `app.blade.php`**

Este código quiero pasarlo a un archivo javascript por separado, pero que sea dinámico ya que será subido a un hosting.

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#login', function (e) {
        /* EVITAR EVENTO DEFAULT DEL BOTON */
        e.preventDefault();

        let email = $('#email').val();
        // alert(email);
        let password = $('#password').val();
        // alert(password);

        $.ajax({
            url    : '{{url('admin/auth')}}',
            method : 'post',
            data   : {
                _token  : '{{csrf_token()}}',
                email   : email,
                password: password
            },
            success: (data) => {
                console.log(data);
                if (data !== 'Éxito') {
                    toastr.options = {
                        'closeButton'      : false,
                        'debug'            : false,
                        'newestOnTop'      : false,
                        'progressBar'      : false,
                        'positionClass'    : 'toast-top-right',
                        'preventDuplicates': false,
                        'onclick'          : null,
                        'showDuration'     : '300',
                        'hideDuration'     : '1000',
                        'timeOut'          : '5000',
                        'extendedTimeOut'  : '1000',
                        'showEasing'       : 'swing',
                        'hideEasing'       : 'linear',
                        'showMethod'       : 'fadeIn',
                        'hideMethod'       : 'fadeOut'
                    };
                    toastr.error(data);
                } else if (data === 'Éxito') {
                    toastr.options = {
                        'closeButton'      : false,
                        'debug'            : false,
                        'newestOnTop'      : false,
                        'progressBar'      : false,
                        'positionClass'    : 'toast-top-right',
                        'preventDuplicates': false,
                        'onclick'          : null,
                        'showDuration'     : '300',
                        'hideDuration'     : '1000',
                        'timeOut'          : '5000',
                        'extendedTimeOut'  : '1000',
                        'showEasing'       : 'swing',
                        'hideEasing'       : 'linear',
                        'showMethod'       : 'fadeIn',
                        'hideMethod'       : 'fadeOut'
                    };
                    toastr.success(data);

                    setTimeout(() => {
                        window.location = '{{url('admin/dashboard')}}';
                    }, 1500);
                    {{--window.location = '{{url('admin/dashboard')}}';--}}
                }
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no se si entendí bien tu pregunta, pero veo que lo que usas de la sintaxis de *blade* allí es el `csrf_token` ¿verdad? pues sencillo.

Lo recomendable es que atiendas esa solicitud Ajax en una ruta de **api** de *Laravel*, crea una nueva ruta de este tipo, que use el middleware `api` y apunte a tu metodo de ese controlador; al hacer esto no necesitas el `csrf token` con *jQuery*. solo envía la solicitud con la data necesaria y lo demás.

Además es lo ideal para ese tipo de solicitudes, las web en tu `web.php` y las de ajax en tu `api.php`

Lo digo porque yo uso Axios y Laravel, no he usado jQuery pero tengo entendido que en este caso funciona igual

Comment: Gracias compa, osea tu solución creo que funcionaría pero llevo aprendiendo Laravel 8 hace un día  y no entiendo aún el manejo del middleware ni las rutas con api, pero lo que necesito es ¿Cómo puedo transformar el {{url('admin/auth'')}} en código javascript? para no tener que poner 'http://localhost/admin/auth' si esque existe alguna manera, o sino ya tocaría hacerlo manual (supongo).

Comment: No te preocupes por eso, no es muy complicado, Laravel internamente hará lo que necesites, en cuanto a lo de usar 'localhost/admin/auth', hazlo sin problemas, claro que cuando lo subas a producción, cambia 'localhost' por el nombre de dominio

Comment: Te recomiendo usar un constante para eso, `const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/'`o cual sea tu ruta base, y la concatenas en las solicitudes `baseUrl + 'turuta'` ya en producción solo cambia el valor de la constante

Comment: Muchas gracias compa me sirvió mucho tu respuesta. 

Comment: Me da mucho gusto!!